# Remove duplicates when values are swapped in columns and give a count

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, data-cleaning

I have a DataFrame like this:

| Col1 | Col2 | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 0.6 |
| A | B | 0.6 |
| B | A | 0.6 |
| A | C | 0.8 |
| C | A | 0.8 |
| D | E | 0.9 |

I want to remove all duplicates even if the values are swapped in col1 and col2 and count such occurrences.

I know we can remove it with

```
df.drop_duplicates()
```

For cases when values are swapped but the meaning is same, then I am creating a temp column which is [col1,col2] and re-arranging the list in ascending order to delete it again using the duplicates method above.

I need to count all these duplicates too. Is there a better way to do this? The resultant DataFrame should be like this:

| Col1 | Col2 | Duplicates | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 3 | 0.6 |
| A | C | 2 | 0.8 |
| D | E | 1 | 0.9 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you could use a `frozenset` as grouper:

```
group = df[['Col1', 'Col2']].agg(frozenset, axis=1)

(df
 .groupby(group, as_index=False)  # you can also group by [group, 'Score']
 .agg(**{c: (c, 'first') for c in df},
      Duplicates=('Score', 'count'),
     )
)
```

output:

```
  Col1 Col2  Score  Duplicates
0    A    B    0.6           3
1    A    C    0.8           2
2    D    E    0.9           1
```

Comment: Would `set()` work also instead of `frozenset()`?

Comment: @mozway - Thanks, this works as intended. May I know what is this .agg() function doing, so that I can expand it to multiple columns in the future if needed.

Comment: @jch I think `frozenset` is needed because it is immutable, where `set` is mutable. a `frozenset` can be used as a dictionary key, while a `set` could not.

Comment: @jch rhug123 is correct, `groupby` requires to hash the elements, thus a `set` wouldn't work.

Comment: @trojanhorse which `agg`? The first one is used to transform to frozenset (it applies the frozenset to each row), the second one is used to aggregate per group, you can see the [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way using `np.sort`

```
df[['Col1','Col2']] = np.sort(df[['Col1','Col2']].to_numpy(),axis=1)

(df.groupby(['Col1','Col2']).agg(
    Count = ('Score','count'),
    Score = ('Score','first'))
 .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
  Col1 Col2  Count  Score
0    A    B      3    0.6
1    A    C      2    0.8
2    D    E      1    0.9
```